# Why does this access query work and the other does not?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that filters based on a boolean value on a form (Task Archived). The boolean value is stored as a long in the underlying table (only 0 and -1 are allowed).

I wanted to write a query that would either show only those records that are false (records not archived) or all records.

I would have expected the follwing query to work, but it does not... it returns only those records for which the archive field is set to `True` (-1):

```
SELECT tbl_Tasks.TaskID, tbl_Tasks.TArchive
FROM tbl_Tasks
WHERE (((tbl_Tasks.TArchive)=
    IIf([Forms]![frm_Activity]![txtArchivedTaskDisplay]=0,False,
    (tbl_Tasks.TArchive)=0 Or (tbl_Tasks.TArchive)=-1)));
```

The query below, which I would expect to show only those records that are `True`, in fact returns all records:

```
SELECT tbl_Tasks.TaskID, tbl_Tasks.TArchive
FROM tbl_Tasks
WHERE (((tbl_Tasks.TArchive)=
    IIf([Forms]![frm_Activity]![txtArchivedTaskDisplay]=0,False,
    (tbl_Tasks.TArchive)<>0)));
```

Why is this? **What logic is access follwing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put SQL where condition within `IIF`. Anything within IIF will be evaluated if possible. Since you only have 0 or -1 below evaluation will always be true.
`((tbl_Tasks.TArchive)=0 Or (tbl_Tasks.TArchive)=-1) => true`

that's why you are only seeing `TArchive = true`

You could try something like this for your first query:

```
WHERE 
tbl_Tasks.TArchive **<** IIf(displayArchivedOnly,0,1);
```

for the second one:

```
WHERE 
    tbl_Tasks.TArchive = [Forms]![frm_Activity]![txtArchivedTaskDisplay]
```

assuming your `txtArchivedTaskDisplay` holds either true or false value like a toggle button. but again, read more about how iif works.

Comment: I understand and see the error in the first query now. Thank you! But your statement "You cannot put SQL where condition within" still leaves me a bit puzzled. I'll mark this as the answer as it explains the reason why the first statement didn't work. For the record, the second query i posted, does in fact give me the result i want... it's just that i didn't understand why it does, but I'll look further into the IIF as you suggested and maybe then i will.

Comment: ps. i bookmarked your website for later purusal. :- ) good stuff. Danke!